# How can I get the position of an element relative to another element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

So I have a div like:

```
<div class="uiGrid">

<div class="trigger"></div>

</div>
```

And I want to know the position of trigger to uiGrid and have tried both these:

```
$('.trigger').offset('.uiGrid');

$('.trigger').position('.uiGrid');
```

but neither get it. Offset is relative to the document and position is relative to the parent and not the specified element.

How would I do this?
Thanks

Comment: Try to change your wrapping div's position to relative in the CSS. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842432/jquery-position-isnt-returning-offset-relative-to-parent]

Answer (score 91, accepted):

just do the subtraction your self...

`var relativeY = $("elementA").offset().top - $("elementB").offset().top;`

Comment: worked perfectly on Chrome, but Firefox gives totally different numbers 

Comment: For my use case, since the Firefox numbers are off by a bit, all I did was a   round `relativeY` to the nearest tenth 

Answer (score 12):

what you can do here is basically, subtract parent property value from child property value.

```
var x = $('child-div').offset().top - $('parent-div').offset().top;
```

Comment: where to put theses subtracting value ?

Comment: thanks” is appreciated. Sorry i forgot to show it by assigning to a variable.
so what you have to do is just define a variable and assign the subtracting value.

var x = $('child-div').offset().top - $('parent-div').offset().top;

Comment: Why did you feel the need to post a redundant answer 2.5 years after the an accepted answer was posted?

Comment: This is exactly the same as the chosen answer from 2.5 years earlier, as VictorKilo says. OOps, this comment is redundant!

Comment: It clarifies which element's position is subtracted from the other. See child/parent vs. A/B

Comment: @MaxStrater Perhaps. but they could have commented on the original answer or at least give some kind of credit to the OP.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the point here....

Besides that, try:

```
myPosY = $('.trigger').offset().left - $('.uiGrid').offset().left;
myPosX = $('.trigger').offset().top - $('.uiGrid').offset().top;
```

Comment: oh but : myPosY  is top , myPosX is left

Answer (score 4):

The problem for me was the fact that I was in a div with a scrollbar and that I had to be able to take into account the hidden part down to the root element.

If I use ".offset()" it gave me wrong values, because it does not take into consideration the hide part of scrollbar as it is relative to the document.

However, I realized that the ".offsetTop" property relative to its first parent positioned (offsetParent) was always correct. So I made a loop to go recursively to the root element by additionning the values of ".offsetTop":

I did my own jquery function for that:

```
jQuery.fn.getOffsetTopFromRootParent = function () {
    let elem = this[0];
    let offset = 0;
    while (elem.offsetParent != null) {
        offset += elem.offsetTop;
        elem = $(elem.offsetParent)[0];
        if (elem.offsetParent === null) {
            offset += elem.offsetTop;
        }
    }
    return offset;
};
```

You can use the same with ".offsetLeft" I suppose...

If you want to get position of element relative to another element to answer the question:

```
let fromElem = $("#fromElemID")[0];
let offset = 0;
while (fromElem.id.toUpperCase() != "toElemID".toUpperCase()) {
    offset += fromElem.offsetTop;
    fromElem = $(fromElem.offsetParent)[0];
}
return offset;
```

> An element (offsetParent) is said to be positioned if it has a CSS
>   position attribute of relative, absolute, or fixed.