# How to determine if an HTML element is VISUALLY to the left, right, top or bottom of another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to determine what would be the best way to know the "visual" position (not the DOM tree position) of an element in relation to another element.

For example, I have an array of elements, and I have a slected element, and want to know which of those elements are visually positioned to the right of the selected element.

Also note that the elements can be of any tag type, and may have any position (relative, absolute, fixed) and display (as long as it's visible).

Any jQuery solutions are welcome.

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Comment: Get the position of the element to compare and element to be compared using `position()` and do the comparison.

Comment: [jQuery get position of element relative to another element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342667/jquery-get-position-of-element-relative-to-another-element)

Comment: I was trying to calculate stuff using `position()` but that was not working as expected. Tried it with `offset()` and it does seem to be giving the coordinates I need for the calculations. So thanks @SpYk3HH

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply use `element.offsetTop` and `element.offsetLeft` where `offsetTop` is the y-axis, and `offsetLeft` is the x-axis.
No jQuery needed at all, though if you insist `$(element).offset();` will probably do.

Note that the top-left corner of the window is the 0-0 point. elements "stuck" to the left will have `offsetLeft === 0`, the ones to tsticking to the top have `offsetTop === 0`. That's all there is too it, really

In response to zeaklous' comment:
To get the *dimensions* of an object:

```
var dimension = {top:    {x:  element.offsetLeft, y: element.offsetTop},
                 bottom: {x: element.offsetWidth, y: element.offsetHeight}
};
```

Be advised, that `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` have been known to return 0 in some cases where the DOM has just been redrawn (getting these properties from an element you've just altered can cause this).
To avoid that, some people tend to use `setTimeout();` when getting the offset of an element that they suspect might just have been altered.

In response to the comments, I've been pointed out that you can simply use `getBoundingClientRect` to avoid any issues with the `offsetX` properties:

```
document.getElementById('foo').getBoundingClientRect();
```

This returns an instance of the `ClientRect` object, with which you can play. [Check MDN for details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect)

Comment: You might also mention that it offset only gives the starting positions of the objects. If one object is within another then it could have a later (as in higher x or y) than the first but also end before the first ends. You could check to see if that is the case by adding the object's width to `offsetLeft` and adding the object's height to `offsetTop`

Comment: @Zeaklous: I've tought about posting a snippet from an old tag-cloud script I wrote some time ago, but that would take us too far off of what the OP actually wants (just to know the position of an element), and that would leave him with nothing to do. Computation of collision of elements on different z-axis... oh what fun I had with that :P

Comment: yeah, the code span "offsetLeft" in zeaklous's comment has an offsetTop of 89, but the "add comment" link under the OP has a value of 199. How can something above something else have a higher y-axis?

Comment: `offsttTop` and `offsetLeft` both start at 0 at the top left corner of your window

Comment: @dandavis: not sure if I quite follow your comment (I'm off to bed, it's late here), but the `add comment` link is _below_ all current comments. So the `offsetTop` of the comments will always be lower (y=0 is the top of the screen)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, no, i mean the one under the post, not this answer. at any rate, this is what elm.getBoundingClientRect() was invented for...

Comment: As Zeaklous mentions, `element.offsetTop` and offsetLeft don't quite work because they seem to give the coordinates in relation to their parents, and if I'm comparing elements with different parents then it won't be accurate. jQuery's `ofsset()` seems to do the trick, I was using jQuery's `position()` but it works similar to `element.offsetXXX`