# How to bind click event on image added using CSS 'background-image' property in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is my fiddle [link](http://jsbin.com/otisur/1/edit)

I guess my question is clear by title itself. Still, what I am looking for is an way to bind `click` event on the image added using css's `background-image` property.

I know, I could have achieved the similar functionality (*of placing image over input field* using [this way](http://jsfiddle.net/vnodkumar1987/nxKRX/3/) or [this way](http://jsfiddle.net/vnodkumar1987/8sbpn/176/)) by simply positioning `<img>` tag over `input` box and then handling the required events but that way didn't seem too flexible with input fields of varying width and height or if the wrapping div doesn't have `position:relative;` as its property.

If adding event on image loaded with `background-image` is not possible then how to make the later approach more flexible.

Hope I have conveyed my issues clearly.

Thanks.

Comment: Incredibly good and difficult question.

Comment: Honestly, I think the only way to approach this is the way you don't want to, placing the image OVER the input box (or hanging it off the right edge) and then dynamically dealing with the placement and size of the inputs themselves.

Comment: the link this way is not working..I do not understand what you are trying to achive

Comment: @sandino link edited now check

Comment: Nice I understand now, I will publish an answer that maybe helps you

Comment: @sandino looking forward for it :)

Comment: Since the image is not an element in the document, it does not trigger events and you cannot bind a handler to it. You have to use a workaround.

Comment: @aug works for me but you can try this link as well http://jsfiddle.net/vnodkumar1987/BShKb/

Comment: @FelixKling agreed with the point but still thinking and looking for - could it be?

Comment: @Bingo yeah it works. Not sure why it didn't before. Interesting question... you might need to use cursor click detection to see where the user clicks within the input box and fire an event that way... The way CSS goes about adding that background-image to your input box is it creates padding and doesn't actually give you an element to interact with :/

Comment: @Bingo are you open to workarounds or does it need to be in this manner? That is with only an input element?

Comment: @Dom yeah of course I am open to workarounds as well but that should be flexible

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this appears to also work:

```
$('.cross').click(function(e) {
  var mousePosInElement = e.pageX - $(this).position().left;
  if (mousePosInElement > $(this).width()) {
     $(this).val(''); 
  }
});
```

[Link to example](http://jsbin.com/ihehan/1/edit)

Comment: WoW!! it works +1 - will accept it shortly :) after getting few more alternatives

Comment: Woowww ...that's what I was talking about...You rock men!! really, I will publish my horrible solution only to note the elegant way you just do it man

Comment: @Brian Hoover one more ques why it changes the text box width on keypress - I changed it a bit -  http://jsbin.com/ohajoq/1/edit

Comment: The CSS was slightly wrong.  The class 'none' needs a '.' in front of it.

Comment: @BrianHoover how could I miss that (.) even with my 4 eyes, might be the case of working till morning :)

Comment: I think it should be clarified this doesn't actually "bind a click event on an image added using CSS" but rather detects where the mouse and the picture is. Great answer though.

Answer (score 2):

So you need to bind the click event to the image but not using an embebed  attributte that's really a very good and dificult question by the way.

I know my approach is complicated but is the only I can figure right now.

You can get the image size (widthImage and heightImage) and know the position relatives of one to another (here is a way of calculating a position of an objet relative to anohter:[jQuery get position of element relative to another element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342667/jquery-get-position-of-element-relative-to-another-element)) you may use it to calculate the position of the input in the whole screen

and try something like this:

$(document).ready(function(){

```
  $('body').on('click', 'input.cross', function (e) {
        var widthInput = parseInt($(this).css('width'),10);
        var heightInput = parseInt($(this).css('height'),10);

        var position  = $(this).position();
        var top       = position.top;
        var left      = position.left;    

        var sizesRelativesInPercentage = $(this).css('background-size').split(/ +/);

        var widthPorcentage = parseInt(sizesRelativesInPercentage[0],10);
        var heightPorcentage =  parseInt(sizesRelativesInPercentage[1],10);

        var widthImage = (widthInput * widthPorcentage)/100;
        var heightImage = (heightInput * heightPorcentage)/100;

        var xFinalImageFinish= (left+widthInput);
        var yFinalImageFinish = (top+heightInput);


        // Fire the callback if the click was in the image
        if (e.pageX >= xFinalImageStart && e.pageX <= xFinalImageFinish &&
            e.pageY >= yFinalImageStart && e.pageY <= yFinalImageFinish) {

            // Prevent crazy animations and redundant handling
            $(this).off('click');
            alert('click on the image');

            //Do whatever you want
        }
    });
});
```

This is only an idea...I am trying to make a fiddle about this, hope so :O

Comment: haven't implemented your script but it looks promising +1

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @Felix King

> Since the image is not an element in the document, it does not trigger
>   events and you cannot bind a handler to it. You have to use a
>   workaround.

Here is a possible work-around (in jquery, but could just as easily be POJS).

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    padding: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px LightGray inset;
}
.wrapperFocus {
    border: 2px DarkGray inset;
}
.textInput {
    padding: 0;
    border:none;
    outline: none;
    height: 20px;
    width: 150px;
}
.cross {
    float: right;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-image:url('http://s20.postimg.org/6125okgwt/rough_Close.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size:90%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

HTML

```
<fieldset class="wrapper">
    <input type="text" class="textInput" /><span class="cross"></span>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="wrapper">
    <input type="text" class="textInput" /><span class="cross"></span>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="wrapper">
    <input type="text" class="textInput" /><span class="cross"></span>
</fieldset>
<hr>
<button>submit</button>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).on("click", "span.cross", function () {
    $(this).prev().val("");
}).on("focus", "input.textInput", function () {
    $(this).parent().addClass("wrapperFocus");
}).on("blur", "input.textInput", function () {
    $(this).parent().removeClass("wrapperFocus");
});
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/ZT9am/)

Or if you want to do it without the additional CSS and HTML, then this should be cross-browser (POJS as you already have a jquery example).

CSS

```
.cross {
    height: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    background-image:url('http://s20.postimg.org/6125okgwt/rough_Close.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right center;
    background-size:10% 90%;
    z-index: -1;
    padding-right: 6%;
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="cross" />
<input type="text" class="cross" />
<input type="text" class="cross" />
<hr>
<button>submit</button>
```

Javascript

```
function normalise(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.target = e.target || e.srcElement;

    return e;
}

var getWidth = (function () {
    var func;

    if (document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
        func = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle;
    } else if (target.currentStyle) {
        func = function (t) {
            return t.currentStyle;
        }
    } else {
        func = function () {
            throw new Error("unable to get a computed width");
        }
    }

    return function (target) {
        return parseInt(func(target).width);
    };
}());

function isInputCross(target) {
    return target.tagName.toUpperCase() === "INPUT" && target.className.match(/(?:^|\s)cross(?!\S)/);
}

function isOverImage(e) {
    return (e.clientX - e.target.offsetLeft) > getWidth(e.target);
}

function clearCrossInput(e) {
    e = normalise(e);
    if (isInputCross(e.target) && isOverImage(e)) {
        e.target.value = "";
    }
}

document.body.onclick = (function () {
    var prevFunc = document.body.onclick;

    if ({}.toString.call(prevFunc) === "[object Function]") {
        return function (ev) {
            prevFunc(ev);
            clearCrossInput(ev);
        };
    }

    return clearCrossInput;
}());
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/wTSp2/)

But if you want the cursor to change when hovered over the position then you will need to do some extra work. Like this (you could just as easily do this with jquery too).

Javascript

```
function hoverCrossInput(e) {
    e = normalise(e);
    if (isInputCross(e.target)) {
        if (isOverImage(e)) {
            e.target.style.cursor = "pointer";
            return;
        }
    }

    e.target.style.cursor = "";
}

document.body.onmousemove = (function () {
    var prevFunc = document.body.onmousemove;

    if ({}.toString.call(prevFunc) === "[object Function]") {
        return function (ev) {
            prevFunc(ev);
            hoverCrossInput(ev);
        };
    }

    return hoverCrossInput;
}());
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/eMmVE/)

Comment: If that's how google resolved this issue I recommend @BrianHoover to work for them...he propused a very simple solution, not css needed, not extra html tags..I am not saying this is not a good solution too

Comment: Changed it to more javascript based.

Comment: @Xotic750 +1 great you you did it anyhow :)

Answer (score 1):

I do something similar by using an `<input type="text" ... >` immediately followed by an `<input type="button">`

The button is given a background image and positioned-relative to move it into the text field; essentially...

```css
position: relative;
top: 4px;
right: 1.6em;
height: 16px;
width: 16px;
border: none;
```

Then I just add a dead-plain click handler to the button, no computations necessary.

The height x width would depend on your image, and you would tweak the top and right to fit your situation.

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stephen61/W9pC5/) shows it pared down to the bare essentials.