# jQuery : calculate the Distance of the li element from the ul

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div class="cntainer">
    <ul class="products">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

i want to calculate the li's position from ul using jQuery.
i tried following code but not getting right result.

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('.products li').offset().left;
    jQuery('.products li').offset().top;
});
```

i want to count the distance of clicked each li  element from ul.

how to calculate top and left from ul for each li..?

Comment: do subtract from the ul position.have a look at this link once.(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342667/jquery-get-position-of-element-relative-to-another-element)

Comment: Well first of all you are targeting the wrong class, in your code. Use `'.cntainer li'` instead of `'.products li'`.

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/72ZFn/